# Retrieve a Sub-string from a string after the first occurrence of a character from a range of characters

Tags: java

i am trying to retrieve a sub-string from a string from the first occurence of any character between A-Z and a-z

for example:

if the string is 13BHO1234FO

then substring should be BHO1234FO

i.e the string from the first occurence of the character 'B'.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did it not work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  It simply deletes the first part of the string you don't want and returns the rest.  The original string is unchanged.

```java
String[] testCases =
        { "13BHO1234FO", "ARSTOP123!", "133KSLK", "122222" };

for (String s : testCases) {
    String sub = s.replaceFirst("^[^A-Za-z]+", "");
    System.out.println("'" + sub + "'");
}
```

Prints substrings surrounded by single quotes to show the string.

```
'BHO1234FO'
'ARSTOP123!'
'KSLK'
''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `regex` and `Matcher` to find the index of the first alphabetical character and make a `substring` starting from the index:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "13BHO1234FO";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        matcher.find();
        int index = matcher.start();
        String substr = text.substring(index);
        System.out.println(substr);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there are no letters in the input?

Comment: This is not included in the question, but a simple try catch would do. @Andreas

Comment: A simple `if` statement would be better. Showing that `if` statement in the answer would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "13BHO1234FO";
    System.out.println(test.replaceFirst("^.*?(?=[A-Za-z])", ""));
}
```

Comment: Why not just `replaceFirst("^[^A-Za-z]+", "")`?